# What's wrong with this C program? (Global variables)

Tags: c

I am new to C and im trying to work with Global variables i ran this program and all get as output is "Hey there" Which is the first part of the program. The second part doesn't get displayed. Here's the code.

```
char count[20]="Hey there";
char dig[7]="pooop"; 

main()
{
    puts(count);

    return(0);
}
hey()
{
       printf(" i %s you", dig);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You never called the second function...

Comment: After the line ```puts(count);``` write ```hey();```.  It can be on the same line, the next line -- it must be prior to the ```return(0);```

Comment: why do people put answers in comments?

Comment: @Ned Batchelder - I would feel dirty if I received any points for this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the second function `hey()` before you can get its output.

E.g., in `main()`

```
{
   puts(count);
   hey();
   return 0;
}
```

where exactly you put the call to `hey()` in `main()` is up to you (it needs to be before the `return` statement though).

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke the function `hey()` someplace if you want it to run.  C programs start with `main()`, and whatever `main` does is what the program does.  Call `hey`  from `main` if you want `hey` to run.

Answer (score 1):

The function `hey` isn't called.  I can't really explain this further without writing a programming textbook here.  So you'll need to find one.